# How can I compare the child values in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase tree]

I am using firebase realtime database to track the inventory on a track. I am doing something simple. As you can see in the image above an item has been added twice to the database instead of adding the quantities. How can I check that an item with a certain SKU and location_name already exists in the database?

Comment: Show us the code that produces that behavior. To understand better, the question is *how to check if a record already exists in the database?*, right?

Comment: I did actually try to upvote, but for some reason they are not letting me give you that vote.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the inventory per product, and products have unique keys already, consider using that existing key in the database, instead of using `push()` to generate a new unique ID.

So where you now do something like:

```
db.push().setValue(objectForSkuPVC005PBPSTA);
```

Instead do:

```
db.child("PVC005PBPSTA").setValue(objectForSkuPVC005PBPSTA);
```

That way you can always update the child at `db.child("PVC005PBPSTA")` when you need to change its quantity.

---

A second unrelated point: you're storing the quantity as a string. I recommend storing it as an actual number, so that you can use numerical operations (such as the new `ServerValue.increment()`) to manipulate it.